# How to make the choice of front page depending on domain name in Joomla website

Tags: php, joomla

I have a website, let's call it mydomain.com, hosted by host provide Siteground.

I have created a subdomain, let's call it sub.mydomain.com, and 
I have set the root folder of the subdomain the same as the main domain.
As a result, the subdomain shows the same contents, in every of its pages, as the main domain.

Now I would like to have a different home page for the main domain and for the subdomain.

So I wish write a php code (maybe in the index.php of the root folder), so that, depending on the value of the current domain name ("mydomain.com" or "sub.mydomain.com"), the default home menu is set accordingly.

The website is based on Joomla 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Virtual domains a joomla extension which can help you to have different templates and content for your demo site. You dont need to hack any core files. As it will be difficult for you to update later. The link is http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/virtual-domains. This link also will help you https://docs.joomla.org/Multiple_Domains_and_Web_Sites_in_a_single_Joomla!_installation.

Comment: I tried the Virtual domains extension, but for the moment I have removed it because it conflicts with the Joomfish language switcher. The second link instead gave me the perfect solution of my request, thank you. In concrete, I have used the php redirect described in option 2.

Comment: @A.Amori Glad that it helped you.